# Restricted Extradimensional Movement: A Death Sentence?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

If a creature in an extradimensional space is subject to an effect that prevents extradimensional movement does the creature drop out of the extradimensional space when the spell that created the extradimensional space ends?

For example, a creature is affected by the spell *dimensional anchor* while in the extradimensional space created by the spell *rope trick* (perhaps cast by another in the same *rope trick* extradimensional space). Normally the creature "drops out when the [*rope trick*] spell ends" but the spell *dimensional anchor* "completely blocks extradimensional travel."

Is the creature who's the subject of the *dimensional anchor* spell and present in the extradimensional space when the *rope trick* spell ends essentially removed from existence, the resident of a now-destroyed extradimensional space?

Comment: Is there any reason to believe that the answer isn't DM's discretion?

Comment: Well, maybe it is, but it's much more fun to put all the facts on the table 8)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its an interesting hypothesis that has no definitive answer in the rules.  By analogizing to how an actual anchor works, if there is no plane to anchor on to, then the Dimensional Anchor should stop working... So if the Rope Trick lapses before the Dimensional Anchor, the Dimensional Anchor would go with it and the affected character would be dumped out of the collapsing extradimensional space exactly as if he had voluntarily waited out the Rope Trick.  That is, however, just one possible interpretation.  I favor it as it isn't unbalancing.

On the other hand, observe how situationally rarified the circumstances in which this exploit would be useful.  Theoretically, I suppose you could grapple or dominate a target into going into a Rope Trick then Dimensionally Anchoring him, but there are more reliable ways of achieving similar effects.

As a personal note, I'm actually a big proponent of ambushing PCs who think Rope Tricks and other extradimensional space effects provide a foolproof sanctuary, but I think this would be a silly and unfun exploit.